# Package hyperref Warning on Abstract

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, abstract

With the following code, I get TWO errors on the line \begin{abstract}, one saying "Misplaced alignment tab character &" which doesn't make sense because I'm not citing anything, so no & is misplaced in my citations
and Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocencoding): remove \unskip on input line 61 - which is the \begin{abstract} line
I understand perhaps \texorpdfstring would be a solution here, but I'm unclear how to input that exactly into this type of "bookmark"

```
    \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linktocpage,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor= red,
    filecolor=red,      
    urlcolor=cyan}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in}

\begin{document}

\title{The Ethics of Software: A Systematic Mapping Study of Ethical Concerns 
in Software Engineering
\thanks{Supported by my school.}}

\titlerunning{The Ethics of Software: A Mapping Study \& Focus Group}

\author{My name\inst{1}\orcidID{2643038}}

\authorrunning{my name}

\institute{my school
\email{my email}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: The warning about `&` could be because you use `&` in the `\titlerunning` command, change that to `\&` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: that did fix the warning of the & symbol! thanks for that. However, I still have the Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocencoding): remove \unskip on input line 61 issue

Comment: After I fix the MWE (properly close the `\title` command with `}` and replace `&` with `\&`) I don't get any errors or warnings. Could you verify that the hyperref warning indeed occurs on this example code? If not, then you have some other code in your real document that triggers the warning.

Comment: I have adjusted the MWE to include more to provide a better MWE

Comment: The issue is the `\thanks` command in the title, which contains a lot of LaTeX code that cannot be converted to pdf metadata. Use `\title{\texorpdfstring{full title\thanks{Supported by my school.}}{full title}}` (so first the part that will actually be in the document, including the `\thanks`, and then the part intended for the pdf metadata).

Comment: Let's close this question as a duplicate of the general _Token not allowed in a PDF string_ question.

Comment: The issue was resolved by editing the \thanks title- but I think it is a specific nuance to that Token not allowed question that deserves its own question